Where did Storyboard Segues' "Presentation" field go in XCode 15?
I'm trying to learn Interface Builder with the aid of a book and some online tutorials but everything is a little bit out of date. It's all written in the time of XCode 13 and I'm using XCode 15 now. Mostly, it's fine but I'm struggling to find the "Presentation" field that used to be in Storyboard Segues. At least, all the screenshots I'm seeing in the book and tutorials show it that way.
I've attached a screenshot of what I see in XCode 15.

Most of the fields are still there but I can't set the presentation to full screen. I gather that it's possible to do this in code with a custom segue but that kind of defeats the purpose, which is learning Interface Builder. Has presentation been moved somewhere else? Is there a setting I need to enable in order for it to show up? Or has it just been removed and there's no way of doing this directly in Interface Builder any more?
I tried the various inspectors but I don't see presentation in any of them. I expected to see presentation alongside the segue type.

You need to select Present Modally kind


Ah, I see. Thanks. The tutorial I'm following is telling me to select "Push" with "Full Screen", but Modal with Full Screen seems to give the correct result so it must just be a mistake in the tutorial. Thanks!
